# How to download files in headless firefox with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

It is possible to download files with Selenium in firefox in normal mode with those capabilities:

```
  "moz:firefoxOptions": {
    "prefs": {
      "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "text/calendar",
      "browser.download.folderList": 2,
      "browser.download.dir": "/tmp"
    }
```

Is it possible in headless mode ? How ? (it is not working for me)

Comment: What errors / exceptions do you receive in headless mode? What screen size do you set in headless mode?

Comment: @Prophet As I check "about:downloads" to see if the file is downloaded and it is not, I get an error. In headless like in normal mode, the window is maximized.

Comment: Maximised doesn't mean much in headless mode (because it's not "attached" to a screen).  The window is likely running at the default size of 1366x768.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know if this is has to do with my problem. It seems that capabilities are not considered in headless mode.